# Merging two items in Array on conditions

Tags: ruby

I have an array with hash objects. The array looks like this:

```
[
  {"name"=>"Red", "id"=>177, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"light", "id"=>355}], "owner"=>false},
  {"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"dark", "id"=>135}],"owner"=>true},
  {"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},
  {"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true}
]
```

I would like to merge the hashes by `name` into the one with `owner=>true`. So, in the above since there are two `Red` the `shades` of them will be merged into one while keeping properties of the one that has `owner=>true`

Finally looking like this:

```
[
  {"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"dark", "id"=>135}, {"shade"=>"light", "id"=>355}],"owner"=>true},
  {"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},
  {"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"light", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true}
]
```

How should I do this? Should I iterate over the array while keeping color names in a unique set?

Comment: I've added more details as people felt it was unclear.

Comment: By `keeping properties of the one that has owner=>true` you mean everything except `shades` which are tu be summed?

Comment: @BroiSatse That is correct

Comment: There is no rush on accepting an answer.  Your question has been up for less than an hour.  You don't want to discourage others from posting additional, possibly better, answers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland 4 close votes are confusing me. Perhaps I'm not doing a great job of explaining the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland if the answer works what compensation does one get for solving the OP's question, he always has a choice to reject and accept better answers, and it is well known on SO that the accepted answers are not always the best answers

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. You need to do an edit, without delay, to clarify. Perhaps something like the following.   I would like to merge all elements of the array that match on the value of the key "name".  "owner" is guaranteed to be true for exactly one hash in each group to be merged.  All attributes for the merged hash other than "shades" are to be from the hash for which "owner" is true.  The value for the key "shades is to be an array containing the values of "shades" for all members of the merged group. Whew! Is that correct?  Best of luck!

Comment: @bjhaid, everyone knows there is no guarantee of a reward for an answer on SO, even if you come up with the greatest answer of all time. Many of us have had the experience of giving a killer answer that received no votes, while inferior answers piled them up. SO is unfair! Life is unfair!. Yes, askers can change their best-answer choice, but many new to SO don't know that or don't want to offend. Lastly, many SO members believe it unprofessional to ask for one's answer to be upvoted and/or selected (as opposed to giving a gentle nudge when no answer has been selected after a few days).

Comment: @CarySwoveland he said my solution worked somehow, and he was going to try it on his dataset, then subsequently asked for explanation, I would suggest you read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), to understand that what I did is in no way wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution:

```
ary = [                                                                                
  {"name"=>"Red", "id"=>177, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"light", "id"=>355}], "owner"=>false},                                                                                  
  {"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"dark", "id"=>135}],"owner"=>true},
  {"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},                                                                                  
  {"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true }                                                                                    
]  

ary.group_by { |h| h['name']}.values.map{ |ary| 
  ary.sort_by{ |h| h['owner'] ? 1 : 0 }.inject { |merged, new| 
    merged.merge(new) {|key, old, new| key == 'shades' ? old + new : new }
  }
}
```

### Result:

Note: I assumed that you don't care about the order under shades key

```
[
  {"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"light", "id"=>355}, {"shade"=>"dark", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true}, 
  {"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true}, 
  {"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true}
]
```

### Explaination:

Firstly, you need to group your data by name. `group_by` does exactly what it sounds it does - it returns a hash with keys being a block results and values being all the elements of ary giving some results. The key is not needed, so we just called `values` to get an array of arrays.

Now each internal array contains all the hashes which need to be merged into one. `merge` takes an optional block to decide what to do if both hashes have the same key (by default it overwrites it with new value). I have decided to sort the array first, so the one with `owner => true` is the last one to be merged. Then block passed to `merge` simply needs to check whether the key is `'shades'` and sum given arrays for this key, for rest go with new value.

Comment: Good answer.  I agree that merge with a block is the way to go here. I have three suggestions: 1. Reformat so no horizontal scrolling is required (code, input and output). 2. Explain about your use of the form of merge that takes a block. 3. Consider using `each_with_object` rather than `group_by. I think it might simplify.

Comment: What I meant by my third suggestion was to build a hash with the value of "names" as the key, then take the values of that hash.

Comment: I do not doubt what you say, @bjhaid, and it was good you pointed it out, but I also expect we won't have, to wait long for a fix, as the approach is fundamentally sound.

Comment: Spelling error: explanation.  I'll delete this comment when I see you've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
j = [                                                                                
  {"name"=>"Red", "id"=>177, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"light", "id"=>355}], "owner"=>false},                                                                                  
  {"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"dark", "id"=>135}],"owner"=>true},
  {"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},                                                                                  
  {"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true
}                                                                                    
]
```

Using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), the return value of the block is passed as the second parameter to the block while the first parameter is the `yielded` object from the `array`(`j` in this answer), the first time the loop runs the second parameter (`arr`) is set to the argument supplied to `each_with_object` which is an empty array (`[]`)

```
j.each_with_object([]) do |hsh,arr|                                              
  if arr.last && arr.last["name"] == hsh["name"] && arr.last["owner"]  
  #This clause checks if the `arr.last` is non-nil (as `nil` in ruby is `falsy`) just to ensure that `arr` is not empty, if the lookup of `"name"` key of the current yielded hash is same as the name element of the last element stored in `arr`, and the lookup of `"owner"` key is `true` then concat the `"shades"` lookup from the current yielded element to that of the last element in `arr`             
    arr.last["shades"] += hsh["shades"]                                              
  elsif arr.last && arr.last["name"] == hsh["name"]   
  #This clause is similar to the previous except it does not consider the `"owner"` key lookup, and it replaces the value `"id"`, `"owner"` of the last element in `arr` with that of the `hsh` while it still concats                                       
    arr.last["id"] = hsh["id"]                                                       
    arr.last["shades"] += hsh["shades"]                                              
    arr.last["owner"] = hsh["owner"]                                                 
  else                                                                               
    arr << hsh                                                                       
  end                                                                                
end 

#=> [{"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"light", "id"=>355}, {"shade"=>"dark", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},
{"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},
{"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true}]
```

Comment: can you please explain how you're solving it? It seems to be working so far but i'd like to understand the process.

Comment: I misunderstood your code when I first read it, but like your solution.  You might consider an outer `if arr.last && arr.last["name"] == hsh["name"]..else..end` and an inner `if arr.last["owner"]..else..end`, before the outer `else`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks, however I don't like nesting `if` clauses as it makes the code more difficult to parse by the eye, I avoid them when I can

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

**Code**

```
owners, nonowners = ary.partition { |h| h["owner"] }
h = owners.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["name"]] = g }
nonowners.each { |g| h[g["name"]]["shades"] << (g["shades"].first) }
h.values
```

**Explanation**

```
ary = [                                                                                
  {"name"=>"Red",   "id"=>177, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"light", "id"=>355}],
   "owner"=>false},
  {"name"=>"Red",   "id"=>195, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"dark",  "id"=>135}],
   "owner"=>true},
  {"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale",  "id"=>135}],
   "owner"=>true},
  {"name"=>"Blue",  "id"=>191, "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale",  "id"=>137}],
   "owner"=>true}
]
```

First divide the array into one array containing the owner hashes and a second array containing the non-owner hashes.

```
owners, nonowners = ary.partition { |h| h["owner"] }
  # owners=>
  #  [{"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195,
  #    "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"dark", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true}, 
  #   {"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192,
  #    "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},
  #   {"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191,
  #    "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true}],
  # nonowners=> 
  #  [{"name"=>"Red", "id"=>177,
  #    "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"light", "id"=>355}], "owner"=>false}]]
```

Next, construct a hash whose values are the hashes in the `owner` array and whose keys are the values of the "name" attribute for those hashes (i.e., "Red", "Green" and "Blue").

```
h = owners.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["name"]] = g }
  #=> {"Red"=>{"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195,
  #      "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"dark", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},
  #    "Green"=>{"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192,
  #      "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},
  #    "Blue"=>{"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191,
  #      "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true}}
```

Now add the "shades" attribute of each nonowner hash to the corresponding owners hash for the key "names".

```
nonowners.each { |g| h[g["name"]]["shades"] << (g["shades"].first) }
```

`h` is now:

```
h #=> {"Red"  =>{"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195,
  #      "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"dark","id"=>135}, {"shade"=>"light","id"=>355}],
  #      "owner"=>true},
  #    "Green"=>{"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192,
  #      "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},
  #    "Blue"=>{"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191,
  #      "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true}}
```

Lastly, extract the values from this hash.

```
h.values
  #=> [{"name"=>"Red", "id"=>195,
  #     "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"dark","id"=>135}, {"shade"=>"light","id"=>355}],
  #     "owner"=>true},
  #    {"name"=>"Green", "id"=>192,
  #     "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>135}], "owner"=>true},
  #    {"name"=>"Blue", "id"=>191,
  #     "shades"=>[{"shade"=>"pale", "id"=>137}], "owner"=>true}]
```